# Which POSIX system calls may block a process ?

Tags: unix, posix, blocking, nonblocking

Is there a reference document somewhere that describes the blocking behaviour of POSIX system calls ?

So far my heuristic has been to flag as potentially blocking any function that may fail with `EINTR` ? Is that a necessary and sufficient condition ?

Comment: I don't have a list, but I suspect that it is not a necessary condition. For example, `unlink(2)` does not specify `EINTR` as a possible error, but it may block (on disk access). There are probably many others like it.

Answer (score -1):

Frankly, to the best of my knowledge, just look at the `man` pages and use common sense. Even if a call doesn't specify EINTR, think about what it does. I may be wrong, but it seems to me that every call in the POSIX library blocks by default and will only execute in nonblocking mode if you ask it too (via various flags), but  I haven't seen a single call that is unblocking by default (that would do anything *but* unblock).

Comment: As a counter example to your claim that 'every call in the POSIX library blocks by default', the `getpid()` system call does not block; period.

Comment: `man` pages don't give enough information and I don't trust my common sense. Examples are `socket(2)`, `shutdown(2)`,  `fnctl(2)` with command F_SETFL, etc. That's why I would like to have a comprehensive document that tells me this.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: But it isen't asynchronous either. It does return the value that is its job to return, which means that it is not nonblocking. It's not like you call `getpid()` and then execute other code and then get the result later.

Comment: @DanielBünzli: For `fnctl()`, that's my point. You had to give a flag to make it nonblocking. As for the others, I have no clue. How precise do you need to be about this? Are you writing some really performance critical code that can't afford to wait at all? What about `shutdown(2)` and `socket(2)`? What are they an example of?

Comment: Right, when I say blocking, I say blocking for an undeterminate amount of time, as Jonathan Leffler understood.

Comment: May the call to `fnctl(2)` block for an undeterminate amount of time ? May `shutdown(2)` block for an undeterminate amount of time ? May `socket(2)` block for an undeterminate amount of time ? It's not about peformance it's about never blocking a main thread for an undeterminate amount of time, delegating the call to a set of worker thread instead, I'd like to avoid useless delegations.

Comment: I see. Well, for that, that could be almost every function in the POSIX library. Anything that accesses the disk, variable. Anything that has network access, variable. Even a function that only does RAM access can have variable time if the memory has been swapped, because the kernel may have to spin up the disk, finish other writes, etc. If it is that crucial to have exact performance, I think you need to rethink your design or just write something that runs a kernel level (as a kernel).

Comment: @DanielBünzli: Unless I'm missing something crucial, that's the problem. Everything that does anything can block for an indeterminate period of time. Disk access will, network access will, storage access will, RAM access can. What is the margin of error we're looking at here?

Comment: Think of a single threaded server serving via IO multiplexing. If a call blocks you want to serve the others meanwhile.

Comment: Then use the unblocking function, or multithread the server. `fork(2)` makes that easy. And the two can mix. Imagine a server where the main thread uses IO multiplexing, but it tells another thread to actually do the serving.